# Runing a functions project locally

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions

I am truing to get a existing .Net functions app runing locally. It has been developed on Windows with Visual Studio, but I am on a Mac (M1 CPU) and using VS Code. I am pretty new to .Net I am struggeling to figure out what needs to be configured to get the project running.

I have added a launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to .NET Functions",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:azureFunctions.pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

and a local.settings.json:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    }
}
```

and there is a tasks.json already in the project:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "clean (functions)",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "args": [
                "clean",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "type": "process",
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Naboor.Statistics"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "build (functions)",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "type": "process",
            "dependsOn": "clean (functions)",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Naboor.Statistics"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "clean release (functions)",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "args": [
                "clean",
                "--configuration",
                "Release",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "type": "process",
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Naboor.Statistics"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "publish (functions)",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "args": [
                "publish",
                "--configuration",
                "Release",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "type": "process",
            "dependsOn": "clean release (functions)",
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Naboor.Statistics"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "func",
            "dependsOn": "build (functions)",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Naboor.Statistics/bin/Debug/net6.0"
            },
            "command": "host start",
            "isBackground": true,
            "problemMatcher": "$func-dotnet-watch"
        }
    ]
}
```

Should I be able to run this project from the commandline somehow? Do I need to point to a task in the tasks.json?

If I run it with F5 in VS Code, I get this error:

```
Executing task: func host start

Can't determine project language from files. Please use one of [--csharp, --javascript, --typescript, --java, --python, --powershell, --custom]
Can't determine project language from files. Please use one of [--csharp, --javascript, --typescript, --java, --python, --powershell, --custom]
Can't determine project language from files. Please use one of [--csharp, --javascript, --typescript, --java, --python, --powershell, --custom]

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.4544 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.3.2.18186

Can't determine project language from files. Please use one of [--csharp, --javascript, --typescript, --java, --python, --powershell, --custom]
Can't determine project language from files. Please use one of [--csharp, --javascript, --typescript, --java, --python, --powershell, --custom]
[2022-05-25T12:24:12.674Z] Failed to initialize worker provider for: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.4544/workers/python
[2022-05-25T12:24:12.682Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Architecture Arm64 is not supported for language python.
[2022-05-25T12:24:12.991Z] Failed to initialize worker provider for: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-functions-core-tools@4/4.0.4544/workers/python
[2022-05-25T12:24:12.991Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Architecture Arm64 is not supported for language python.
[2022-05-25T12:24:13.118Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation 'a0f1f8a3-92f6-434a-9ab1-17055f0828f4'.
[2022-05-25T12:24:13.118Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost: Secret initialization from Blob storage failed due to missing both an Azure Storage connection string and a SAS connection uri. For Blob Storage, please provide at least one of these. If you intend to use files for secrets, add an App Setting key 'AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType' with value 'Files'.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
The terminal process "/opt/homebrew/bin/zsh '-c', 'func host start'" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

I thought that was what the

```
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
```

part of local.settings.json was for?

I am pretty new to this, can anybody guide me on the correct path?

Thank you
Søren

Comment: Check that you in the right directory that includes the project file.. not some top level or other directory. Then type dotnet restore and then type func start

Comment: Can you update your post with the contents of the .csproj file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have tried the same in our local and able to run it successfully.

I believe that you are just missing the configuration in your local .

Here are the steps :-

- Make sure the [**`Azure function runtime`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash#v2) , [**`Dotnet sdk`**](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download), storage emulator has been installed in your local . If not you can download from VS CODE extension called [**`AZURITE`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio-code#install-azurite) instead of emulator as it has been deprecated.
- In VS CODE install extensions Azure where all the tools will be available , c# (Any language that you want to prefer) & Azure function being installed.

[image]

[image].
[image]

- If you want to create new project click f1> Select create new azure function . As you have existing file there is no need to point `task.json` file once the aforementioned has been done test your project by running :

. `dotnet build` once build succeed run ,

. `func host start` (If you have existing/new project don't run `func init` as it will create one more `.csproj` file and then it may occur to fail)

***SNAPSHOTS FOR REFERENCE:-***
[image]

***STORAGE EMULATOR STARTED IN LOCAL:-***
[image]

[image]
[image]

For more information please refer this **MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**| [***STEP BY STEP TUTORIAL TO CREATE AZURE FUNCTION IN VS CODE.***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs-code?tabs=csharp)

Alternatively, If you want to learn using Visual studio Create Azure function on *Macos* please refer this [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/azure-functions?view=vsmac-2019).

Answer (score 7):

As it was not explicitly mentioned, the effect of multiple output errors comes with the missing *local.settings.json* file. *This answer is explicitly for Visual Studio 2022 users, NOT Visual Studio Code*!

For reference the erroneous output:

```
Executing task: func host start

Can't determine project language from files. Please use one of [--csharp, --javascript, --typescript, --java, --python, --powershell, --custom]
Can't determine project language from files. Please use one of [--csharp, --javascript, --typescript, --java, --python, --powershell, --custom]
Can't determine project language from files. Please use one of [--csharp, --javascript, --typescript, --java, --python, --powershell, --custom]

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.4544 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.3.2.18186

Can't determine project language from files. Please use one of [--csharp, --javascript, --typescript, --java, --python, --powershell, --custom]
```

If you have added the file locally from another source (through the **add existing item** feature), Visual Studio will keep in the project, but will not copy it to the publish directory. This step is often necessary because this file is in *.gitignore* and hence not pulled from your repo.

In *.csproj* it will look like this:

```
<None Update="local.settings.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
</None>
```

Just remove the line

```
  <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
```

and that it is. To prove it just run `func host start` in the project's root from command line and it will work, as this works on the project itself without the publishing step performed by Visual Studio.

It might als happen that the copy step is entirely missing, then either add the step or use the **copy always** feature in Property window (F4) of VS.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for me. My issue was I had nested objects in the local.settings.json and apparently looks like that is not allowed. After removing it outside of the nested, it worked. So yeah any minor issue like an extra ; or } would show up as this error.

Comment: Nesting in AppSettings, KeyVault, App Configuration and other tools that are organised as a key value struct (dictionary) is possible, indeed. However, to overcome the limitation it's usually organized by some special chars: Prop__NestedObj__Prop (double underscore in App Configuration) or Prop--NestedObj--Prop (double dash in KeyVault). Retrieve in code using the Prop:NestedObj:Prop syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Create local.settings.json file:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to configure VSCode launch tasks etc I would recommend installing the Azure Functions extension from the marketplace:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azurefunctions

Once that is installed you can open the project and it will likely detect the functions project and ask if you want to initiliase for use with VSCode. If it does not then you can use the option from the command palette.

[image]

You may also be able to just run `func init` against the project to initiliase any files that may be missing.

**Please ensure any files are tracked in git or backed up before making changes to the existing files**

Having worked with Azure Functions on both Windows and Mac (non-M1) I would highly recommend using devcontainers for development. This means you don't have to have the SDK/Runtime/Functions Core Tools installed locally and means anyone using the project can just spin up the container and begin debugging without having to install a bunch of dependencies.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers

Comment: I did run "func init", that is what gave me the local.settings.json, and I just tried running the VS Code plugin init also, but still it gives the "Can't determine project language from files" error message?

Comment: Seems it could be an issue witht the `local.settings.json` as per this github issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2050. I've only ever developed functions in VSCode so never had to deal with Visual Studio differences.